# New HP Pavillion laptop has lines on screen

Tags: display, hp-pavilion

I just got a brand new hp laptop (pavillion, 13-0033ur)  and it shows tiny white horizontal lines on screen. Both in windows and bios. External display is just fine, no artifacts on screen.
I have updated video driver for integrated Intеl UHD 620.
Is it a definitely hardware problem or should i try to fix it by updating all possible software?

[image: example]

Comment: I would send it back for a refund or exchange for a new one that works.

Comment: Thank guys, just sent it back, will know what was wrong in 10 days.